# Creating polyline templates (polyline vs polyline ZM) for future network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, network-analyst, 3d-analyst, polyline-creation

I am about to request large amounts of polylines from a variety of sources (municipalities). The idea is to collect bike path data and build a regional bike network (I work for the region administrative board).

To help municipalities (and myself once I need to assemble all the data), I plan to create template files. I now realize I do not know enough about network datasets and 2D to 3D conversions. I basically don't know what I don't know, hence this very open question.

I have:

- Arcgis 9.3 (hopefully 10.2.1 in the fall but not for certain).
- High resolution DEM of the region.
- limited bike path shapefiles (segmented polyline ZM, not a network
  dataset)

I need:

- advice in creating template shapefiles that are easy and flexible enough for the municipalities to use and still be fairly straight forward for me to put together for a network.
  The templates will contain 3 attributes (short integers) that denote road type, traffic situation and recreational value.

specifically I would like to know more about polyline vs polyline ZM? - bear in mind that the municipalities are using a variety of software (CArcGIS, MapInfo, CAD(?) etc. etc.).

Comment: They should all be able to export to Shape files. The simplest would be to assume only 2D is available and then take Z from the DEM and they will all be on the same datum. Plus you can use 2D snapping to connect up the network at the edges of municipalities before adding Z. However the problem is that cycle routes do like tunnels, so without Z there will be false intersections where an underpass "connects" with the road going over it.